# ObjectManager in category init

Tags: magento2, category, object-manager

Why Magento is using `$this->_objectManager->create()` directly in function _initCategory in file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category.php`?

```
protected function _initCategory($getRootInstead = false)
    {
        $categoryId = $this->resolveCategoryId();
        $storeId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        $category = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::class);
        $category->setStoreId($storeId);

        if ($categoryId) {
            $category->load($categoryId);
            if ($storeId) {
                $rootId = $this->_objectManager->get(
                    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class
                )->getStore(
                    $storeId
                )->getRootCategoryId();
                if (!in_array($rootId, $category->getPathIds())) {
                    // load root category instead wrong one
                    if ($getRootInstead) {
                        $category->load($rootId);
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Registry::class)->register('category', $category);
        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\Registry::class)->register('current_category', $category);
        $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config::class)
            ->setStoreId($this->getRequest()->getParam('store'));
        return $category;
    }
```

As per the Magento recommendation, we should include class/object in constructor using DI. So, why is it so?

Or Am I reading this code incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were using `objectManager` before DI constructor was ready. Now there is no time to fix all usages of object manager. But if you are writing new code you should always use DI constructor.